# patterns for storing/retrieving Backbone.js View instances associated with dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

When we create instances of views in Backbone.js, we assign a root dom element that becomes this.el inside of the view. Inside our Backbone.js app we probably have references to the view instance, so it's easy to work with the view. However let's say there's another script on the page that doesn't have a reference to the view instance, but knows which dom element represents the view (this.el). Is there a built-in way in Backbone.js to retrieve the view instance from the dom element so code that doesn't have a reference to the view instance can get to the instance? I'd like to do something like this:

```
var viewInstance = $("#rootElId").data("bb-myview");
```

I am unaware of a built-in functionality like this in backbone.js, but I thought I'd ask just in case one does exist.

Secondly, if this isn't built into Backbone.js, then what is a good way to implement my own functionality like this? Are there good patterns out there I can just copy?

Thanks!

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013848/backbone-js-given-an-element-how-do-i-get-the-view

Answer (score 0):

We use marionette layouts and regions to accomplish this type of functionality

The way that you create a layout

```
var AppLayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: "#layout-view-template",

  regions: {
    menu: "#menu",
    content: "#content"
  }
});

var layoutView = new AppLayoutView();
layoutView.render();
```

Display a view in a region

```
layoutView.menu.show(new MenuView());
```

Getting the view from the region

```
var viewInstance = layoutView.menu.currentView // here you can get the actual view instance
```

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layoutview.md

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md

Thanks

Comment: How exactly does that solve an issue? You still cannot access the view view DOM element, right?

Comment: @Dethariel you can access the DOM element of the current view instance just by asking by the .el element of the viewInstance, using regions will give you many benefits like this one or not having to worry about zombie views.

Comment: In this solution you have to store the reference to the view (`layoutView` in your example). The question is: "How do I access view without storing a view"

Comment: It does,you can decide if it fits your necessities or not.It is not about different scripts, everything is about context, as you can see on the example, regions represent DOM elements, so if you know the element you know the region, you use the region to get access to the view instance that is currently displayed on it, that's it. If you cannot access the app/layout/region context under your current one, there is no way that you can get or manipulate the backbone instance of your view, obviously you can access the DOM  element with jquery, but it is a diff thing.   Thanks,even 4 your -review

Comment: @Dethariel the question is  Are there good patterns out there I can just copy?